# Does Doctrine/DBAL is compatible with PHP5.6?

Tags: doctrine, php-5.6

Doctrine ORM seems to need PHP5.3 and next one's.

There is no information about Doctrine DBAL I want to use. I think the ORM is based on DBAL, so it should be PHP5.3+, but is there any breakdown to make it work with last PHP release (5.6).

Comment: This class metadata patch seems enough for now to run it: http://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/87237/Doctrine--2-3-6-on-PHP----5-6-%28vendor-do/

Comment: Otherwise you need to use 2.5 ORM (master branch).

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1. Use Doctrine ORM 2.5 codebase (currently master branch, not yet stable).
2. Apply this patch to ClassMetadataInfo class:

`--- ClassMetadataInfo.php 2014-07-07 08:46:51.658104373 -0400
+++ ClassMetadataInfo.patch.php 2014-07-07 08:38:05.442127032 -0400
@@ -827,7 +827,7 @@
    public function newInstance()
    {
        if ($this->_prototype === null) {
-           if (PHP_VERSION_ID === 50429 || PHP_VERSION_ID === 50513) {
+           if (PHP_VERSION_ID === 50429 || PHP_VERSION_ID === 50513 || PHP_VERSION_ID === 50600) {
                 $this->_prototype = $this->reflClass->newInstanceWithoutConstructor();
            } else {
                 $this->_prototype = unserialize(sprintf('O:%d:"%s":0:{}', strlen($this->name), $this->name));`

Source: http://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/87237/Doctrine--2-3-6-on-PHP----5-6-%28vendor-do/